# Idris interface syntax

Tags: syntax-error, typeclass, idris

I am trying to compile simple example of `interface` in Idris.

```
interface Foo a where
     foo : a -> String
```

But I keep getting this type-checking error:

```
error: expected: "with",
argument expression,
function right hand side,
implicit function argument,
with pattern
interface Foo a where 
                ^
```

I believe it should be logically the same as the `Show` interface in the tutorial: http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/interfaces.html Has the syntax changed? Or where could be the problem?

I am using Idris version 0.9.12.

Comment: It works with Idris 0.12.3.

Comment: Upgrading fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Idris 0.9.12, the syntax for what is now called interfaces is `class`:

```
class Foo a where
     foo : a -> String
```